# configuring jars dependencies in pom

Tags: maven, libraries

I have a project developed in java using eclipse. This project is using a set of jars. We are trying to execute now this project using maven.
I have configured the pom file for every jar dependecy smth like:

```
<dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.uml2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>uml</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
```

I am trying to use same version of libraries we have in the project.
I am facing two problems:
1. If i just specify the library just like this it gives me error that it can not download from the default repository that maven is using.
2. if i specify the repository in my pom smth like:

```
<repositories>
     <repository>
       <id>Indigo Release</id>
       <url>https://raw.github.com/eclipse/acceleo/master/maven/repository/releases/indigo</url>
     </repository>
     <repository>
       <id>Juno Release</id>
       <url>https://raw.github.com/eclipse/acceleo/master/maven/repository/releases/juno</url>
     </repository>
     <repository>
       <id>Snapshots</id>
       <url>https://raw.github.com/eclipse/acceleo/master/maven/repository/snapshots</url>
     </repository>
   </repositories>

   <pluginRepositories>
     <pluginRepository>
       <id>Indigo Release</id>
       <url>https://raw.github.com/eclipse/acceleo/master/maven/repository/releases/indigo</url>
     </pluginRepository>
     <pluginRepository>
       <id>Juno Release</id>
       <url>https://raw.github.com/eclipse/acceleo/master/maven/repository/releases/juno</url>
     </pluginRepository>
     <pluginRepository>
       <id>Snapshots</id>
       <url>https://raw.github.com/eclipse/acceleo/master/maven/repository/snapshots</url>
     </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
```

than the version which is in this repositories is not  the one i want to download.
I tried to download libraries manually in my local repository but its a lot of work. Isn't there any simple way to do this ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration could not work cause the raw accesses to github will give you error 401 but to get forward check the [wiki of Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven).